# Why does MVC automatically expand virtual URLs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my `Layout.cshtml` file I have the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
```

My assumption was that since I did not include `Url.Content()` call, it would actually just render what I wrote but not expand the virtual URL automatically. This assumption is wrong - the generated HTML does include the correct path to the file, not the virtual path I entered.

If I wrap the `<link>` in `<script>`

```
<script type="text/html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
</script>
```

then the URL is not expanded.

Which part of ASP.NET MVC does this automatic parsing of HTML and is there a way to control it?

Comment: When do you ever want a URL starting with `~/`?

Answer (score 3):

This was a new feature included in Razor2 and ASP.NET MVC 4 and was designed to make life easier by not having to use `Url.Content` everywhere.

http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2

The feature only works inside *standard* HTML attributes and that's why you don't get it inside your `<script>` tag or anywhere else.

You could use a simple output write to work around this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" />
```

Comment: Is there some more documentation on this processing? For example, that would explain why it does not replace it inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation